# Change the order of col-*-12 columns in Bootstrap 3 using push/pull

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, push, pull

I have a little problem.
I have three columns on xs and sm like this :

[A]

[B]

[C]

On md and lg, I want this :

[B]

[A][C]

I have tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8 col-md-push-12">
  Col A
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-md-pull-12">
  Col B
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
  Col C
</div>
```

The columns A and B are outside :(

Thank you

Comment: I don't think it's possible to change the order of elements with bootstrap, but you can do this with CSS grid

Answer (score 0):

You can easily reorder columns in bootstrap [with the order classes.](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#order-classes)

> Use .order- classes for controlling the visual order of your content. These classes are responsive, so you can set the order by breakpoint (e.g., .order-1.order-md-2).

An example on how to reorder Col B and Col C on small screens:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8 ">
    Col A
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12 order-sm-3">
    Col B
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 order-sm-2">
    Col C
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but you code only works on Bootstrap 4, and I use Bootstrap 3 :(

Comment: There is no way to reorder this with basic bootstrap3, you can only reorder with flexbox or grid. Please read this note from the bootstrap-tag you are using: `For questions related to a version of Bootstrap also use the specific version's tag from "twitter-bootstrap-2", "twitter-bootstrap-3" and "bootstrap-4" tags.`